# Background Image not showing in mobile browser (but showing in desktop browser)

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem where the first background image on my website shows up on desktop but not on mobile (it's just a gray background). The image is .jpg and the size is 4595p x 2736p (546 KB)

Website in question: https://www.basit.dev/, full code can be found here if desired  https://github.com/Basit-Sheikh/basit.dev

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Here is the relevant code:

CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url(../img/s0.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 80% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

[Example of what it looks like on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBEgf.png)

Comment: I can't take the screenshot on my mobile. but I tested it and it shows the background image. but the load time is long.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can't have a fixed background image on mobile, I used a workaround by writing a simple jQuery script.